# Customer seeing error after successful Click and Pledge Payment

Tags: payment-processor

After a successful payment through the Click and Pledge extension, a customer saw this:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::createElement(): unterminated entity reference
q=civicrm/event/register&_qf_Confirm_display=true&qfKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
in /tcp-wp/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/com.clickandpledge.payment.clickandpledge/CRM/Core/Payment/ClickandPledge.php on line 498

 Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
```

(I substituted the xxx's here for a long alphanumeric string.)

Any thoughts about what I can or should do about this?